# saving long string in android into the sqlite database

Tags: java, android, string, sqlite

i want to save a long String in to a TEXT field in Sqlite but i cant! my String has about 20,000 character. when i save a Substring(1000 char) of that, it works fine but my main long string cant write to database! where is the problem? is there any limitations? where? why? how can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Apparantly, this should work with TEXT just fine: http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html

Perhaps someone inadvertently changed the setting of DSQLITE_MAX_LENGTH, which default setting is around 1GB.

Comment: it doesnt work! i already in my another project i saver 18,000 char string, now i cant even 10,000!! my code is clean, i sut has a String and i want to save it with the same way i did it already in other projects...